# Key to hit "Replace All" button in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, replace, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Xcode 4.6.2's in-file find and replace feature. When programming I don't like touching the mouse if I can help it, so I tab around to enter the find and replace text. Now I want to hit a single key or key combo that will "launch" the replacement—in effect, hit the "Replace All" button. Does such a key exist?

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode->Preferences->Key Bindings type `replace` in the search window.

You'll see ReplaceAll shortcut, put there any key you want.